# Downloading data from Nikon NPL 322

Tags: software-recommendations, total-station

I lost the DVD that came with Nikon NPL 322 Total Station.

What software and programs (and versions) do I need to have in order to download and upload data from  the Total Station (purchased in 2012)?

Comment: What kind of connections (cables) do you have for this total station? (USB, Serial, Bluetooth?)

Comment: I have a serial to USB cable only. The TS has a serial port only.